# How to check the position of an element on a webpage

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I want to check if a certain element (more about block) is always at the top right of a page and above dynamic elements that can be available. How do I do that in Java and Selenium? What methods are best to use?

the elements is as follows:

```
private WebElement MoreAbout() {
    return SharedDriver.getSelenium().findElement(By.ById.id("more_about"));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "above dynamic elements that can be available"? Above how? "Above" as in "having a lower y coordinate"? Or "above" as in "having a higher z-index"? Also, I've performed quite a bit of this kind of testing and can tell you that without more details the answers you're going to get are going to be very generic and unlikely to work in your specific case. (The current answer is exactly that: very generic.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use getSize() and getLocation() depending on your requirement. Find more details [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get x and y offsets

```
  WebElement element = MoreAbout();
  int x = element.getLocation().getX();
  int y = element.getLocation().getY();
```

**Note:** Also it is not good practice to use a method name starting with upper-case.